# добавление python в path

Tags: python, path

Всем приветик. Пытаюсь себе уже какой раз поставить django, но проблема в том что, каждый раз при установке вылетает сообщение про то что python находится не в Path. Сколько не пыталась, в свойствах системы показывает что путь к python есть в переменной path. [image: путь к python в переменной среде для пользователя][image: путь к python в системной переменной][image: ошибка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас прописан путь к python38-32\scripts, а вам надо добавить ещё именно к python38-32

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!. Помогло...

Comment: @Jarryaduck, тогда ответ прими галочкой слева от него.